# Binary classification using radial basis kernel SVM with a single feature

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Is there any interpretation (graphical or otherwise) of a radial basis kernel SVM being trained with a single feature? I can visualize the effect in 2 dimensions (the result being a separation boundary that is curved rather than a linear line. (e.g http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kernel_Machine.png).

I'm having trouble thinking of what this would be like if your original data only had a single feature. What would the boundary line look like for this case?

Comment: hi! assuming that each feature is a dimension, what do you mean that you can "visualize the effect in 2 dimensions"? wouldn't the visualization with a single feature be a simple line with a threshold where the slash is? `<------------/-------->`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics, and was posted here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86458/binary-classification-using-radial-basis-kernel-svm-with-a-single-feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one dimension, your data would be **numbers**, and decision boundary would be simply **finite set of numbers**, representing **finite set of intervals** of classification to one class and **finite set of intervals** of classification to the another one.

In fact, the decision boundary in R^2 is actually the set of points, for which weighted sum of gaussian distributions in support vectors (where alpha_i are these weights) is equal to b (intercept/threshold term). You can actually draw this distribution (in 3d now). Similarly, in 1d you would get a similar distribution, which could be drawn in 2d, and the decision would be based on this distribution being bigger/smaller than b.

Answer (score 1):

This video shows what happen in a kernel mapping, it is not using the RBF Kernel, but the idea is the same:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3liCbRZPrZA

As for the 1D case, there is not much difference, it would be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would look line a line that switches back and forth between two different color (one color for each class). Nothing special happens in 1D besides SVMs being over kill.